# Show custom error message instead of 'Internal Server Error' in postman

Tags: apex, api, postman

Is there any way in apex to show custom error message like 'Invalid Parameter' instead of 'Internal Server Error' when wrong header parameter is passed in postman. I tried using 'throw new exception' things but it didn't help. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You can do with custom translation in Apex but why you want to do that? **Internal Server Error** happens when the server encounters an unexpected condition that prevents it from fulfilling the request. So this error doesn't happens only for Invalid Parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a parameterized method, you can't control the error if the data type is invalid. Consider:

```
@HttpGet public static String method(Id contactId) {
 ...
}
```

This code will throw an error before you gain control in Apex if the ID is invalid, for example, if it's only 14 characters. This is true for both `webservice` methods and `RestResource` classes and methods.

However, if you do your own parsing, you'll gain full control over the response:

```
@HttpGet public static void method() {
  try {
    String jsonRequest = RestContext.request.getBody();
    ...
  } catch(Exception e) {
    RestContext.response.statusCode = 500;
    RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(
      JSON.serialize(
        new Map<String, Object> {
          'success' => false,
          'message' => 'Invalid parameter'
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Note that if you allow an uncaught exception to reach the top of the stack, you lose control of the error message. You must *not* throw an uncaught exception if you want control of the output. Also, note that certain headers can't be caught by Apex, either.

For example, if the `Authorization` header is invalid, your code will never get a chance to run. Similarly, if something like the `Host` header is invalid, the runtime won't give your Apex code a chance to run. This is in contrast to some frameworks, which just run the desired method, even with invalid data, so that the programmer can control the output.